# How to programmatically subscribe messenger webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to implement Facebook Checkbox for my customers but I realized that it's required to subscribe to the `messenging_optins` event to render Facebook checkbox. So I tried to subscribe to the `messaging_optins` event programmatically.

Note that my facebook app is in development app. So in fact, I still test on my Facebook account.

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{my-customer-page-id}/subscriptions?access_token={my_app_access_token}&callback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-server.ngrok.io%2Fwebhook%2Ffacebook&fields=messaging_optins&object=page&verify_token=abc123abc123456"
```

The response is `{"success":true}`

But my Facebook Checkbox still does not work until manually go to Facebook Developer setting and subscribe to the Page as the below screenshot.

[image]

I realize that the above `curl` command just help me subscribe to the Page Webhook (not Messenger webhook) event as the below screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone point me out why I can't subscribe to "Messenger event" but Facebook graph API return that it successfully subscribed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

After 1 day digging Facebook Docs, try and test many cases with Facebook Graph Explorer, I finally found the way to programmatically subscribe to the Page's Webhook.

In Facebook Docs, it had writes 3 lines like this

> Webhooks for Messenger allows you to receive real-time notifications when a variety of interactions or events happen, including when a person sends a message. Webhooks for Messenger works a little differently than other Webhooks so please use the [Webhooks for Messenger docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook) when setting up this type of Webhook.

Here is the way I subscribe `messages`, `messaging_postbacks`, `messaging_optins`, `message_reads` events. Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-pages

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{page-id}/subscribed_apps?access_token={page-access-token}&subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,message_reads"
```

Comment: this returns `(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.` I acquired page access token with `email, public_profile, pages_show_list, pages_messaging, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement` permissions

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Graph API has a `Subscriptions` endpoint which can be used to set up webhooks for graph network's objects(e.g `page`, `user` etc). 
You need to make a `POST` request to the subscriptions endpoint and provide the required parameters, which are:

1. `object` the object whose webhook you're going to subscribe to
2. `callback` the publicly accessible URL where Facebook will be sending the webhook event data when the subscribed event gets triggered(e.g your `page` receives a message)
3. `fields` the list of fields you want to subscribe to(e.g `messages`)
4. `verify_token` Facebook will send this token to your callback URL so that you can verify that it's coming from Facebook and not some malicious source [see this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup/) for handling webhook callbacks
5. `access_token` your app access token
   Here is a snippet from [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge)

```
curl -F "object=user" \
     -F "callback_url=https://your-clever-domain-name.com/webhooks" \
     -F "fields=photos" \
     -F "verify_token=your-verify-token" \
     -F "access_token=your-app-access-token" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com/your-app-id/subscriptions"
```

If succeeded, response will be

```
{
  "success": "true"
}
```

To see the subscriptions you've, send a `GET` request to this HTTP endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/your-app-id/subscriptions?access_token=your-app-access-token
```

which returns a response like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "user",
      "callback_url": "https://your-clever-domain-name.com/webhooks",
      "active": true,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "photos",
          "version": "v2.10"
        },
        {
          "name": "feed",
          "version": "v2.10"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```